# Adding a new user to CRM 4.0 using sdk

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Does anyone have sample code to add a new user to CRM 4.0 using sdk?

Answer (score 2):

I have code that creates users for us based on users in another system so I can't exactly paste it all here - most of it wouldn't make sense to you - but this is the core of it:

[In VB sorry :-) - also when posting VB here I find I need to use '//' to indicate a comment to make the formatting correct]

```
Public Sub CreateNewUser()
  Dim s as mscrm.CrmService = GetMyService()
  Dim newUser as New mscrm.systemuser()
  With newUser
     .domainname = "domain\user"
     .firstname = "Stan"
     .lastname = "Molda"
     //set anything else you want here
  End With
  Dim userGuid as guid = s.Create(newUser)

  //Next we need to assign the user a role
  AssignRole(userGuid)

  //Finally we need to assign them to the correct Time Zone
  SetUserTimeZone(userGuid)
End Sub

Public Sub AssignRole(g as Guid)
    Dim s as mscrm.CrmService = GetMyService()
    Dim req As New mscrm.AssignUserRolesRoleRequest()
    req.UserId = g
    req.RoleIds = New Guid() {GetTheGuidForMyPrimaryRole()}
    s.Execute(req)
End Sub

Public Sub SetUserTimeZone(g as Guid)
    Dim s as mscrm.CrmService = GetMyService()
    Dim r As New mscrm4.RetrieveUserSettingsSystemUserRequest()
    r.ColumnSet = New mscrm3.AllColumns()
    r.EntityId = New Guid(g)
    Dim resp As mscrm.RetrieveUserSettingsSystemUserResponse = CType(s.Execute(r), mscrm.RetrieveUserSettingsSystemUserResponse)
    Dim settings As mscrm.usersettings = CType(resp.BusinessEntity, mscrm.usersettings)
    settings.timezonecode = New mscrm.CrmNumber
    settings.timezonecode.Value = OUR_TIME_ZONE_CONSTANT
    Dim update As New mscrm.UpdateUserSettingsSystemUserRequest()
    update.Settings = settings
    update.UserId = g
    s.Execute(update)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Brendon good job very clear and the perfect solution i wonder why no one even cared to say it is useful... Who ever asked this question should really click as answer to the question...

Answer (score 1):

For C#, take a look at my question, [Dynamics CRM: Create users with specific GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314688/dynamics-crm-create-users-with-specific-guids), which does exactly what you want (but not *exactly* what I want :-P).